# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'starfield_solve' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have seen similar posts with the same problem. I tried to implement other suggested solutions that worked, but somehow it does not work for me. This is shorted example of my code that I am running in jupyter notebook:

```
def starfield_solve(file,verify):
    do_something

def apply_async_callback(src_path, verify):
    with Pool(processes=PROCESSES) as pool:
        multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(
            starfield_solve, args=(file, verify)) for file in files]

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    apply_async_callback(src_path, verify)
```

EDIT:
I am putting down below the minimal reproducible example.
Further note, this exact code works on linux, but it doesn/t work on MacOS Monterey 12.1

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def starfield_solve(num):
    print(num)
    return num

def apply_async_callback():
    temp_dir = [1,2,3]
    PROCESSES = mp.cpu_count() - 1
    with mp.Pool(processes=PROCESSES) as pool:
        multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(starfield_solve, args=(num,)) for num in temp_dir]
        output = [res.get() for res in multiple_results if res.get()]

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    apply_async_callback()
```

And this is the full error:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-20:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/astrometry/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/astrometry/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/astrometry/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/astrometry/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'starfield_solve' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: Please, provide [mre] as well as full traceback you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation on IPython (read as Jupyter Notebook) not fully supporting multiprocessing ([relevant GitHub issue on IPython's repository](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10894)). Use this solution, based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/wandb/client/issues/956#issuecomment-616454600):

1. Put your target function (`starfield_solve`) in a *.py file
2. Import the function from the file
3. Use that function to `apply_async_callback`

So, step 1:

```
# your_module.py
def starfield_solve(file,verify):
    do_something
```

Then, in your Jupyter Notebook, apply steps 2 and 3:

```
from your_module import starfield_solve


def apply_async_callback(src_path, verify):
    with Pool(processes=PROCESSES) as pool:
        multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(
            starfield_solve, args=(file, verify)) for file in files]
```

Comment: Thanks, this way works. I still have to restructure my code because I have multiple functions inside starfield solve. I will wait a little bit more if someone have some other answer and then I will accept your solution